# Did Coinstar add a delay and fake noises because people didn't believe a machine could count coins quickly?

Tags: psychology, technology, consumer-products

I saw a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/i1wkpw/what_is_just_a_placebo_effect_but_most_people/g013jcz/) on Reddit claiming that Coinstar machines are extremely fast at counting coins, but that the company had to introduce a delay and fake noises to the machines because customers didn't trust the accuracy of the machines at such a high speed.

I tried to find a source for this claim, and came across [some posts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=coinstar) on the UX Stack Exchange, all of which cited a [blog post](https://90percentofeverything.com/2010/12/16/adding-delays-to-increase-perceived-value-does-it-work/index.html), which cited a [comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2007818).

Is there any reputable source that backs up the claim that Coinstar added a delay and fake noises to their machines?

Comment: Not only coin machines: someone on the ycombinator link said: *One of the things they found in user testing was that when new users clicked "Create my Blog" on the last step of the setup process, they were confused at how quickly their blog was created. "That's it? Is something wrong?" were the types of things people said. So they added an interstitial "Creating your blog..." type page that did nothing but spin a little animated gif and wait a few seconds before sending new users to the "Yay, your blog is created! page". Users were far more satisfied with the new experience that took longer.*

Comment: I always assumed the fake noise that ATMS make when they dispense bills was to disguise the number of bills actually being dispensed. So, for example, someone behind you in line wouldn’t be able to hear how much money you’re pulling out and decide to try and grab it. Could this be similar?